# Get numbers (might be comma separated) from string

Tags: php, regex

string is "Lorem, ipsum 12 dolorem, si amet 58,14"  and etc. I need to extract "12" and "58,14". I have no experience with regular expresions. So the question is - how should I do this? :)
Language (if this matters) is php5.

Comment: Just think long and hard about different cultures and how they affect stuff like the decimal point in your list. You might have bugs down the line that are going to be very hard to track down and fix if you make the wrong internal format choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$foundMatches = array();
$targetString = "Lorem, ipsum 12 dolorem, si amet 58,14";
preg_match_all('/([1-9]\d*|0)(,\d+)?/', $targetString, $foundMatches);
var_dump($foundMatches);
?>
```

You'll find the needed results at `$foundMatches[0]`.

Edit: Updated regex to not match `123,` or `012`. If you want those use the older `/\d+,?\d*?/`.

Useful reading: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Sorry for posting untested code the first time. This one is tested.

Comment: Your regex is working, but it returns an array with such elements: `[0] => array([0] => '12', [1] => '58,14'), [1] => array([0] => '12', [1] => '58'), [2] => array([0] => '', [1] => ',14')` Is it possible to modify regex so it will only return the found matches like in first element of given array? Cause I need exactly "12" and "58,14" and your regexp returns more than that (which I don't need in a loop).

Comment: @egis Only use `$foundMatches[0]`. If you want you can do `$foundMatches = $foundMatches[0]` to discard the other captured items. Also you can switch to non-capturing groups with `(?:<regex>)` instead of `(<regex>)`, but I thought it would be easier to understand the regex if I used normal grouping.

Comment: By `(?:<regex>)` you mean `'/(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:,\d+)?/'`? `cause it returns exactly what I need :)

Comment: Let me clarify this - I always find the needed results in first array element? No need to loop trough whole array?

Comment: Anyway, your answer is what I need. Thank you! :)

Comment: @egis Yes. I would recommend reading through the reference at regular-expressions.info .